# S8550 reducing current

Tags: transistors, solar-cell, tp4056, 18650

[image]
**Updated Schematic**
[image]
I am trying to set up an external battery storage for solar lights as the solar lights are not in direct sunlight and cannot charge their own batteries.

Each solar light runs off a single 1.2v AA rechargeable Ni-Mh battery.

I have put together 4 18650 cells in parallel. They run into a TP4056. The BMS branches from the negative input terminal to a s8550 to act as an auto on/off switch using the solar panel as a light sensor. The output of the TP4056 runs to a LM2596S stepping the input voltage of 4.2V to 1.26V.

My trouble is, with the LM2596S in place the bulb illuminates very low. But when I remove the s8550 from the circuit the light shines brightly the way it should.

Is there something I can replace the s8550 with as I feel it's the problem reducing my current?

Datasheet URLs
**S8550**
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/SS8550-118608.pdf
**LM2596S**
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf
**TP4056**
https://www.addicore.com/TP4056-Charger-and-Protection-Module-p/ad310.htm

Comment: Please provide a schematic, and indicate how much current the light draws.

Comment: Links to datasheets for your components would also help make this question better and attract more quality answers.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this stuff. I've added a schematic and the light draws .97ma.

Comment: _”TP4056 BMS”_ TP4056 is not a BMS but a linear CC/CV charger IC.

Comment: @winny thank you. Noted

Comment: Ditch the PNP in series and hook yourself into pin 5, enable, on LM2596S. Pull low to enable and pull high to disable.

Comment: @winny I have no idea what that means. Do you mean pin 5 on the JM93MRP? And I'm not sure what you mean by "enable" and by hooking in, do you mean break the input to the LM2596S to let 5 on the JM93MRP and that should do the same as the series s8550? Sorry I'm new to this and learning as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Use the enable pin of the LM2596S to turn on your 1.2 V output when solar is low.

Please note that this is not a complete schematic but rather more of a glorified block diagram.

Resistor divider R3/R4 is added on case your open circuit voltage on the solar panel is above 6 V. "5 V" solar panels are never 5.0 V. Adjust as needed, preferably with a potentiometer until it turns on at reasonable low light level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFyfXn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you for the help with this. I updated my schematic to show what I have done, but I am still having a problem. I must be doing something wrong or missing something. I am using a 1.2V battery in place of the solar panel for testing but when I connect to pin1 the voltage on the LM2596S drops to 0 which is perfect. But when I remove the 1.2V battery simulating no voltage from the solar panel the 18650 battery does not kick in and I have to pull the 18650 to reset everything.

Comment: would it be possible to just use a different transistor instead of the S8550? Something that can handle 1a of current like the BC639? https://components101.com/transistors/bc639-transistor-pinout-datasheet-equivalent-circuit-specs#:~:text=The%20BC639%20is%20an%20NPN,moderately%20high%20voltage%20switching%20applications.